# How to convert a unicode number to a std::wstring?

Tags: c++, unicode, type-conversion, wstring

Is there an easy way to convert a Unicode number to a `std::wstring`?
e.g. I want to convert U+1E9E (=16785054) to `ẞ`.

Comment: C++ doesn't have great built in unicode support.  I suggest using a library like [ICU](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu/)

Comment: `std::wstring str = L"\u1E9E";` can do that.

Comment: It's amazing how questions about Unicode *never make any sense*.

Comment: Assuming the mistake is 16785054 then the simple way to do this is as the comment by @dalfaB states. Or even something like `str[i] = 0x1E9E;`, assuming suitable declarations for `str` and `i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the platform which you are running your code on, the encoding of the `std::wstring` will need to be either UTF-16 (ie, Windows) or UTF-32 (ie, most other OSes). Converting a codepoint number to either of those formats is very trivial.

On platforms where `wchar_t` is 32-bit in size, suitable for UTF-32, you can just cast the number as-is to `wchar_t` and then assign it to your `wstring`.

On platforms where `wchar_t` is 16-bit in size, suitable for UTF-16, you will have to use a small bit of math to convert the number to 1 or 2 `wchar_t`s based on its value, and then assign that result to your `wstring`.

For example:

```
std::wstring CodePointToWString(unsigned int codepoint)
{
    std::wstring str;

    if constexpr (sizeof(wchar_t) > 2) {
        // use UTF-32
        str = static_cast<wchar_t>(codepoint);
    }
    else {
        // use UTF-16
        if (codepoint <= 0xFFFF) {
            str = static_cast<wchar_t>(codepoint);
        }
        else {
            codepoint -= 0x10000;
            str.resize(2);
            str[0] = static_cast<wchar_t>(0xD800 + ((codepoint >> 10) & 0x3FF));
            str[1] = static_cast<wchar_t>(0xDC00 + (codepoint & 0x3FF));
        }
    }

    return str;
}

...

std::wstring str = CodePointToWString(0x1E9E);
```

---

FYI, U+1E9E is not 16785054, it is 7838. 16785054 would be U+1001E9E instead, which is not a valid codepoint.

Comment: Thank you very much Remy!! 
( BTW I am using gdk_keymap_translate_keyboard_state which returns a keyval of 16785054 (U+1001E9E) for AltGr +KeyCode 20 (Linux)

Comment: @user3443063 U+1001E9E is not a valid Unicode codepoint. `gdk_keymap_translate_keyboard_state()` does not output a Unicode codepoint, it outputs a GDK key symbol (aka a keyval) instead. Not the same thing. This is evident by the existence of `gdk_unicode_to_keyval()`, which returns `wc | 0x01000000` if no keyval exists. Guess what `0x1001E9E` is? It's `0x1E9E | 0x01000000`